# sending text file from server to client line by line in winsocks

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

i have a client and a server , when the client connect to the server the server will read a text file , convert it to uppercase and send it line by line to the client .
the text file is named **"text.txt"** and look like this:

[image]

**server code**

```
 #include<io.h>
 #include<iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<winsock2.h>
 #include<winsock2.h>


 #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

  using namespace std;

void stringToUpper(string &s)
  {
 for(unsigned int l = 0; l < s.length(); l++)
  {
   s[l] = toupper(s[l]);
  }
  }

   int main()
  {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s , new_socket;
     struct sockaddr_in server , client;
     int c;
    char *message;

     cout<<"\nInitialising Winsock...";
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
       cout<<"Failed. Error Code"<<WSAGetLastError();
        return 1;
     }

   cout<<"Initialised.\n";

     //Create a socket
     if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout<<"Could not create socket "<< WSAGetLastError();
     }

      cout<<"Socket created.\n";

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
      server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      cout<<"Bind failed with error code : "<< WSAGetLastError();
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

   puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
     listen(s , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

     c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

 while( (new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
       puts("Connection accepted");

      //Reply to the client
    string STRING;
ifstream infile;
infile.open ("text.txt");
     while(!infile.eof()) 
         {
        getline(infile,STRING); 
    stringToUpper(STRING);
        const char *STRING_mod = STRING.c_str();
        send(new_socket , STRING_mod , strlen(STRING_mod) , 0);
        }
         char *end_msg="end";
    send(new_socket , end_msg , strlen(end_msg) , 0);

   infile.close();



       }

     if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
      {
        cout<<"accept failed with error code : " << WSAGetLastError();
         return 1;
      }

       closesocket(s);
       WSACleanup();



      return 0;
       }
```

**client code**

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<winsock2.h>

   #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

   using namespace std;
 int main(int argc , char *argv[])
  {
   WSADATA wsa;
   SOCKET s;
   struct sockaddr_in server;
   char *message , server_reply[2000];
int recv_size;

   printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
    cout<<"Failed. Error Code : "<<WSAGetLastError();
    return 1;
    }

     cout<<"Initialised.\n";

    //Create a socket
      if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
   {
     cout<<"Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError();
   }

   cout<<"Socket created.\n";


   server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
     if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
       puts("connect error");
       return 1;
   }

   puts("Connected");






  recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, 2000, 0);
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    while ( server_reply != "end"){

        cout<<server_reply<<endl;
       recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, 2000, 0);
       server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';

    }






       closesocket(s);
      WSACleanup();


   return 0;
    }
```

when i run the server then the client , i have the following response :

[image]

but this is not the required behavior ,  i want the text appear as it looks in the text file , "line by line" ..... so where is the problem in my code and how i can fix it ? and why the client stuck at the while loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also send a newline. `getline` reads all characters until a newline, but doesn't store the newline in the string. So when you send the string, it doesn't have a newline.

You can either send a `"\n"` on its own, but probably better to add a newline to the existing string.

E.g. :

```
  stringToUpper(STRING);
  STRING += "\n";
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your programs. They are to many to list in a comment so that's why I put them here as an answer.

- In the client, the server reply is stored in an array, and you use that array to compare to the string literal `"end"` which will not work. Either convert the string to a `std::string` or use `strcmp`.
- The client have the data in a `std::string`, but still gets the raw string pointer and use that to calculate the string length using `strlen` instead of the `length` method of `std::string`.
- There seems to be no error checking at all. All socket functions returns `-1` (or `SOCKET_ERROR`) on error, and the `recv` function return `0` when the connection is closed.
- You use "magic numbers" in your code, like the size of the array when receiving in the client. Don't do that, instead (in the case of your client `recv` calls) use e.g. `sizeof(server_reply)`.

And most importantly of all:

- TCP sockets is a *streaming* socket, that means there are no message boundaries and the client can in a single call to `recv` actually receive less than what you asked for, or more than was send in a single `send` call. It's the last thing that happens to you, the `recv` call actually receives *all* that was sent from the server in one call. And since you sent the string without newlines, you receive it without newlines.

  Most protocols using TCP sockets have either a message length included in the message, or some kind of special boundary sequence (most often carriage return and newline (i.e. `"\r\n"`).

Comment: Wow , this is very informative , i which that i could accept two answers to accept this too. ..thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

[getline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ah895zy.aspx) reads all except the delimiter. You have to add LF or CR+LF to the string before sending it.